# FileVersionInfo not working in Win2008 R2

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use following code on my Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit (not SP1).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace TestWrite
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

        FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\Windows\system32\Notepad.exe");

             Console.WriteLine( "File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' + "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
}
```

I get this error message: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'version.dll': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is this a 64-bit or 32-bit application?

Comment: In V.S., platform target is set to 'Any CPU'.

Comment: Just for grins, recompile your application and change the target to X86, which should force the target into a 32-bit application. If the error persists, I'd check for the presence of \windows\system32\version.dll on the target machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check the following:

- The `System.Diagnostics` library works by executing this code

  ```
  EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
  foreach (EventLog e in eventLogs) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}:", e.LogDisplayName);
  }
  ```
- Like [David W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345535/david-w) points out, check the solution platform (`Any CPU` or `x86` via `Solution Configuration Manager`)
- Is the `.NET Framework 4.0` is installed properly? Or try a re-install.

Comment: I'm missing the connection the first bullet point has to the question.

Comment: The first bullet point was another test case to check the framework